Black formatter Server: Start failed: Error: Unsupported server configuration. On VS Code
I've used black formatter extension on VS Code for months and it worked fine, but now (probably due to some updates I guess) it stops.
I use the import strategy fromEnvironment and I installed black in every env that I use.
Now when I open VScode and black try to start the server it gives the following error:
2024-10-02 15:49:14.519 [error] Server: Start failed: Error: Unsupported server configuration {
"command": "",
"args": [
"",
"c:\Users\utente\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.black-formatter-2024.2.0\bundled\tool\lsp_server.py"
],
"options": {
"cwd": "c:\Users\utente\Desktop\PhD\LSST\docs\M2",
"env": {
"ALLUSERSPROFILE": "C:\ProgramData",
"APPDATA": "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming",
"APPLICATION_INSIGHTS_NO_DIAGNOSTIC_CHANNEL": "1",
"CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME": "\\.\pipe\crashpad_14372_LHIMFDDJORKTBJDI",
"COMPUTERNAME": "M3581",
"CUDA_PATH": "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2",
"CUDA_PATH_V11_2": "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2",
"CUDA_PATH_V12_3": "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3",
"ComSpec": "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe",
"CommonProgramFiles": "C:\Program Files\Common Files",
"CommonProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files",
"CommonProgramW6432": "C:\Program Files\Common Files",
"DriverData": "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData",
"EFC_11872": "1",
"ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE": "1",
"FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING": "Internet Explorer",
"FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING": "Default",
"HOMEDRIVE": "C:",
"HOMEPATH": "\Users\utente",
"IGCCSVC_DB": "AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl
+sBAAAAZAjLkAmO8UeyNr7nfNqPpQQAAAACAAAAAAAQZgAAAAEAACAAAAAeeAF3d5xlHXRoR0vPhS9HvHiDEX/
ncvR1Js1WViDgqAAAAAAOgAAAAAIAACAAAADRrsJcJO1G9LZdQvy3gm/PKicuuz8KJqju
+p2pT80YimAAAACiXQwe1T669lQVXnZgw2OW9LEsO3hlQZSDTOJcnUz+8SoQ8RPRpT1f0+ELePnQ9fOpNoqYUhTn1Tz
+1Jiih8q19FlsuFoXRYVJ14CNbkMIP0q6QOcKnhqOC9YhiuBojpRAAAAAG201Zu6noVrKhd+QnyeWg1g4QgFEWZzFd4G6y3lvVdWM6xQzwGK9/
VTN0vi6Gd7BCM8kg4mjPYFN3bs6FDUx9w==",
"LOCALAPPDATA": "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local",
"LOGONSERVER": "\\M3581",
"NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS": "20",
"NVCUDASAMPLES11_2_ROOT": "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v11.2",
"NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT": "C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v11.2",
"NVTOOLSEXT_PATH": "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\",
"ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP": "undefined",
"OS": "Windows_NT",
"OneDrive": "C:\Users\utente\OneDrive",
"PATHEXT": ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC",
"POSH_INSTALLER": "winget",
"POSH_THEMES_PATH": "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\themes",
"PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE": "AMD64",
"PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER": "Intel64 Family 6 Model 186 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel",
"PROCESSOR_LEVEL": "6",
"PROCESSOR_REVISION": "ba02",
"PSModulePath": "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
"PUBLIC": "C:\Users\Public",
"Path": "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVI
GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\libnvvp;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Commo
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\WireGuard\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\include;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\lib;C:\Program Files\NVI
GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\extras\CUPTI\lib64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2020.3.
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\extras\CUPTI\lib64;;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\utente\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files
\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\utente\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program
Files\Siril\bin\;C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Programs\oh-my-posh\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;
C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WinGet\Links;
C:\Users\utente\Desktop\PhD\sci_project\hst1pass;C:\SAOImageDS9\;C:\Users\utente\anaconda3;",
"ProgramData": "C:\ProgramData",
"ProgramFiles": "C:\Program Files",
"ProgramFiles(x86)": "C:\Program Files (x86)",
"ProgramW6432": "C:\Program Files",
"SESSIONNAME": "Console",
"SystemDrive": "C:",
"SystemRoot": "C:\WINDOWS",
"TEMP": "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Temp",
"TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH": "true",
"TMP": "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Temp",
"USERDOMAIN": "M3581",
"USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE": "M3581",
"USERNAME": "Utente",
"USERPROFILE": "C:\Users\utente",
"VSCODE_AMD_ENTRYPOINT": "vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess",
"VSCODE_CODE_CACHE_PATH":
"C:\Users\utente\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedData\38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
"VSCODE_CRASH_REPORTER_PROCESS_TYPE": "extensionHost",
"VSCODE_CWD": "C:\Users\utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code",
"VSCODE_DOTNET_INSTALL_TOOL_ORIGINAL_HOME": "undefined",
"VSCODE_HANDLES_UNCAUGHT_ERRORS": "true",
"VSCODE_IPC_HOOK": "\\.\pipe\39dc64ed-1.93.1-main-sock",
"VSCODE_L10N_BUNDLE_LOCATION": "",
"VSCODE_NLS_CONFIG": "{"userLocale":"en-us","osLocale":"it-it","resolvedLanguage":"en",
"defaultMessagesFile":"C:\\Users\\utente\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS
Code\\resources\\app\\out\\nls.messages.json","locale":"en-us","availableLanguages":{}}",
"VSCODE_PID": "14372",
"ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN": "1",
"windir": "C:\WINDOWS",
"USE_DEBUGPY": "False",
"LS_IMPORT_STRATEGY": "fromEnvironment",
"LS_SHOW_NOTIFICATION": "off"
}
},
"transport": 0
}
I try to change the import strategy as well as uninstall and install agagin the extension.
Moreover, I try black from cli and it works porperly, so it seems a problem with the usage inside VScode.
VScode about:
Version: 1.93.1 (user setup)
Commit: 38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40
Date: 2024-09-11T17:20:05.685Z
Electron: 30.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 10073054
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.15.1
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
Balck info:
black, 24.3.0 (compiled: yes)
Python (CPython) 3.11.7
